# How to check to which DataColumn a DataGridTextColumn is bound to

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I would like to check to which `DataColumn` a `DataGridTextColumn` is bound to.

I am trying to do something like:

```
private void kblMeoravPrDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
     if ((e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.Path == "DBFieldName")
     {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that the value isn't null.

```
var dataGridTextColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
if (dataGridTextColumn != null) // If not null then the column is DataGridTextColumn
{
   //working
}
```